# UITabeView перенос текста

Tags: ipad, xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

Уважаймые iПрограмисты есть проблема с переносом текста в таблице.

Написал код, он должен переносить слова которые не влезают в таблицу в низ. Но он не работает поеу-то и я не могу в понять почему. Помогите !!!

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

    SMXMLElement  *elem=[citation objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *str = [elem attributeNamed:@"text"];
    UILabel *longi = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    longi.numberOfLines = 0;
    longi.text = str;
    [longi sizeToFit];
    float i = longi.frame.size.height+10;
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не уверен, но вроде sizeToFit фиксирует для UILabel ширину и наращивает высоту, а т.к. у вас ширина задана в 0, то ему не удается посчитать необходимую высоту.

Если же брать весь код в целом - не надо создавать отдельную UILAbel, у NSString есть несколько методов которые умеют считать размер куда строка поместится - см. [NSString UIKit Additions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html)